# Скрытие и открытие элемента Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне подсказали скрипт, который должен скрывать див с инфой после открытия меню, но так как SlideToggle мне не подходит по анимации решил применить hide, однако надо чтоб при повторном нажатии на меню(Когда оно закрывается) блок снова появлялся.

```
var w = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();

if (w <= 380) {
    $(".main_mnu_button").click(function() {
    $(".descrip_application").hideToggle(400);  
    });
}
```

Comment: Ну ваш код не полный, вы должны как то условие добавить.

Comment: Каким образом образом меню открывается ?

Comment: $(".main_mnu_button").click(function() {
  $(".nav_top ul").slideToggle();
 });

Comment: так открывается меню

Comment: Как я понял после открытия высота меняется у меню правильно?

Comment: меню абсолютное, просто залазит туда куда не нужно. Нужно как в коде в вопросе чтоб закрывалось но при повторном нажатии на кнопку вызова меню див появлялся обратно

Comment: Вот написал в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто смотреть когда у меню высота не ноль. То есть когда она открыта.

```
$(".main_mnu_button").click(function() {
  $(".nav_top ul").slideToggle(function(){
    if($(this).height() == 0){
      $(".descrip_application").show(400);  
    }
    else{
      $(".descrip_application").hide(400);  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Срабатывает только скрытие дива, а вот открываться обратно он у меня не хочет с закрытием меню

Comment: @Kr1on1x сделайте до ифа `console.log($(this).height())`. И посмотрите какое значение в логе когда во второй раз когда должен открыться блок. То есть 2 раза сделайте клик и посмотрите лог

Comment: Сделал как сказали, но логи мне ничего выдавать не хотят(это же консольный лог браузера правильно?). чет совсем у меня все плохо с этим делом(((

Comment: @Kr1on1x Да и вы их в консоли должны посмотреть, ну или если вам легко можете сделать `alert`